# AWS Sagemaker notebook intermittent 'Unable to locate credentials'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, dask-distributed, python-s3fs

I'm trying to use Dask to get multiple files (JSON) from AWS S3 into memory in a Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook.
When I submit 10 or 20 workers, everything runs smoothly. However, when I submit 100 workers, between 30% and 50% of them encounter the following error: 'Unable to locate credentials'

Initially I was trying with Boto3. In order to try to eliminate this issue, I switched to S3FS but the same error is occurring.

The workers which err out with the NoCredentialError are random if I repeat the experiment, as is the exact number of failed downloads.

Sagemaker is handling all the AWS credentials through its IAM role, so I have no access to key pairs or anything. The ~/.aws/config file contains only the default location - nothing about credentials.

It seems this is a very common use for Dask so it's obviously capable of performing such a task - where am I going wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated! Code and traceback below. In this example, 29 workers failed due to credentials.
Thanks,
Patrick

```
import boto3
import json
import logging
import multiprocessing
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
import s3fs
import os

THREADS_PER_DASK_WORKER = 4
CPU_COUNT = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
HTTP_SUCCESSFUL_REQUEST_CODE = 200

S3_BUCKET_NAME = '-redacted-'

keys_100 = ['-redacted-']
keys_10 = ['-redacted-']

def dispatch_workers(workers):

    cluster_workers = min(len(workers), CPU_COUNT)
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=cluster_workers, processes=True,
                           threads_per_worker=THREADS_PER_DASK_WORKER)
    client = Client(cluster)

    data = []
    data_futures = []

    for worker in workers:
        data_futures.append(client.submit(worker))

    for future in data_futures:
        try:
            tmp_flight_data = future.result()
            if future.status == 'finished':
                data.append(tmp_flight_data)
            else:
                logging.error(f"Future status = {future.status}")
        except Exception as err:
            logging.error(err)

    del data_futures

    cluster.close()
    client.close()

    return data

def _get_object_from_bucket(key):

    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)# uses default credentials
    with s3.open(os.path.join(S3_BUCKET_NAME,key)) as f:
        return json.loads(f.read())

def get_data(keys):

    objects = dispatch_workers(
        [lambda key=key: _get_object_from_bucket(key) for key in keys]
    )
    return objects
    
data = get_data(keys_100)
```

Output:

```
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
ERROR:root:Unable to locate credentials
```